# Enterprise and Open Cryptographic Systems/Applications?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

Please can someone tell me the main Enterprise/Open Cryptographic Systems in use, I am having a hard time googling for them. I know OpenPGP is one, but is that the best and most ubiquitous one for ogranisations/enterprises etc?

I am thinking for authentication, encryption etc. Emails, files, network access etc.

Thanks

Comment: This might be better off on security.stackexchange.com

Comment: This covers an enormous amount of ground, and it isn't clear what you mean by "cryptographic systems".  Many or most of the security protocols in wide use are open, and the IETF has hundreds or thousands that might address your question, as do many of the other questions here at IT Security.  I suggest reading our faq and editing your question (or starting with a new one) to address one problem or application that doesn't already seem covered here.

Comment: Can you clear up whether you mean "Open and Enterprise", or you intend for those to be addressed separately?

Answer (score 1):

One enterprise option is [credant](http://www.credant.com/).  I know that there is a multitude of different tools out there to look at.

As for open source, Truecrypt is always a good tool.  But again, you can find a plethora of options online.

P.S. There's also a nice android app that I use called IOSafe which is a mobile equivalent to to keepass (also a good tool).  Both tools are used to store user account/password information and can also be used to securely save additional information.